# Add a table class name to a View table

Tags: views, 8, theming

Can I add a custom table class name to a View that outputs a table, Or just add the name of the view to the table class name? There isn't a setting in Views to add a table class name, you can only add row class names.

My View name is view-a1. I would like to the name of the View to all table class names.I am trying to do it with hook_preprocess_views_view_table. But I don't know how.

The default twig template uses this markup

The method in the url below worked, it will add a custom hardcoded table class name. I changed the hook in the example to hook_preprocess_views_view_table. What I really want to do it add the name of the View as the table class name. How can I do that?

https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming-drupal-8/modifying-attributes-in-a-theme-file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Datatables too, I had to add an ID to a table generated by a View displaying a page (system name = page_1).
I did that duplicating `views-view-table.html.twig` into `views-view-table--members--page_1.html.twig` and changed

```
<table{{ attributes.addClass(classes) }}>
```

into

```
<table{{ attributes.addClass(classes) }} ID="ListOfMembers">
```

Maybe that can help you...

Comment: `id` must be lower case and the ID itself should better be lower case only as well.

Comment: Apart from that there are functions to be used in Twig to manipulate attributes the right way. For example `<div{{ attributes.setAttribute('id', 'myID') }}></div>`, see [Using attributes in templates](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming-drupal-8/using-attributes-in-templates).

Comment: gbmapo. This worked for me the fastest. I create multiple Datatable configs for multiple View table blocks that are placed on the same page! When I first looked at twig debug name suggestions, I did not see I could rename the table view by the block number, now I see it. I still want to find out how to add the Views block name as a table class name or a table id name automatically instead of hardcoding this ID="table2" inside each new template. My clients also like pasting Datatables inside Ckeditor. When they do they can specify the class/id they want.So Ckeditor Datatable work great.

Comment: leymannx. Yes I think I will use: set classes = [. And then add: .addclass('mytable1') }}>. How can I highlight comments on this site so that they have a grey background color?

Comment: @gbmapo, I created blocks not pages from a View. So my example is for blocks. I found that twig debug originally only gave this limited naming suggestion. `block--views-block--a1-block-1.html.twig` It did not show a suggestion for table. It wasn't until after I created the file you said, this `views-view-table--a1--block_1.html.twig` that  it then gave me a naming suggestion for it? Why is that? I think this article talks about the issue and its a bug in Drupal 8 core. [link]https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!modules!views!views.theme.inc/group/views_templates/8.2.x

Answer (score 3):

Views have the **CSS class** option under `Advanced` (third column). There you can set the class to be output to all displays of that Views or override for single Displays.

Most themes won't output that class directly on the `<table>` element, it is usually output on a `<div>` that contains the table.

That can be enough for styling in CSS, but if you want you can override the twig template or use the preprocess function in your theme for more control.

Comment: Thank you prkos. But I a really need to add the View name to the table class name. I feel like I am close. In the hook views_view_table I can add a hardcoded table class, I am trying to load the view name then create a variable from it then add it as the class name. I am using Datatables JS in the theme not the module. If you have different table configs, you need to use different table class names. Datatables can not target the containing div class.

Answer (score 3):

Try this out it works for me:

```
use Drupal\Component\Utility\Html;
/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_views_view().
 */
function MYTHEMENAME_preprocess_views_view_table(&$vars){
  $view = $vars['view'];
  $vars['attributes']['class'][] = Html::cleanCssIdentifier($view->id());
}
```

Comment: You better add that class to the array instead of redeclaring it, so it needs to be `$vars['attributes']['class'][] = $view->id();`. And if you are really strict with some CSS standards you may also ensure to replace underscores in the machine name with hyphens, maybe using [`Html::cleanCssIdentifier`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Component%21Utility%21Html.php/function/Html%3A%3AcleanCssIdentifier/8.2.x) or with just `str_replace('_', '-', $view->id())`.

Comment: berramou, If that is a preprocess, should it be function MYTHEMENAME_preprocess_views_view_table. Instead?

Comment: @berramou. @leymannx. Thank you, the corrections you made works. There are 2 good answers here. My original question was to add the Views name to the table class that the View outputs. And your method works. I found that I need to add the View 'block number' or 'page number' as the class name. Because my View has multiple blocks and I want Datatables to initiate/target each View block differently. So the template naming method from @gbmapo works. Can I alter this `= Html::cleanCssIdentifier($view->id());` So that it adds the Views block ID/number. In dpm I see `[options][title] => a1block2`

Comment: i'm glad that help , if you want to add display name for example try the following : `$displayObj = $view->getDisplay();
$displayName = $displayObj->display['display_title'];`